# When I change my $scope.model through select within a ui-tabset it doesn't change accordingly

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap, angular-bootstrap

Currently I have my `<select>`  inside of a ui-tabset and when it is inside of a tabset it does not seem to update my `$scope.filter_item_package` correctly when I have it set as the model.

Here is my code:
HTML:

```
<uib-tab index="2" heading="All Harvest Plans">
  <select class="form-control"  ng-model='filter_item_package' ng-change='package_change()' >
   <option ng-repeat=" items in cases_filter_items" ng-selected="{{items.t2}}" value="{{items.t2}}">{{items.t3}}
   </option>
  </select>
</uib-tab>
```

JS:

```
$scope.filter_item_package = 'Cases'
 $scope.cases_filter_items = [
{'id':1,'t2':'Cases','t3':'Show Cases'},
{'id':2,'t2':'Acres','t3':'Show Acres'},
{'id':2,'t2':'Palettes','t3':'Show Pallettes'}
]
$scope.package_change = function(){console.log($scope.filter_item_package)}
```

But when I don't have the options nested inside the ui-tabs it updates correctly. For example, when I change to Acres or Palettes it will console.log accordingly.
This is just a rough draft of what is going on.

Answer (score 1):

I can see at least one problem with your draft.

When you write `ng-selected="{{items.t2}}"`, you are saying:

> if `items.t2` returns `true`, then set this element's `selected` attribute.

And because `items.t2` returns a string, which is 'truthy' in Javascript, you are setting all of your ng-repeat instances to be `selected` by default.

Instead, use `ng-selected="items.t2 === filter_item_package"`.  Note that `{{}}` is not required for ng-* directives.